# Amazon Pay Integration : Where can I get preSharedEncodedKey?

Tags: amazon-product-api, amazon-pay

I'm trying to integrate Amazon Pay for receiving merchant payments and I see a method which receives preSharedEncodedKey. But I can't find that key anywhere in document. Where can I find it?

It is mentioned in [22 January 2019 Amazon Pay Integration Guide 26]

```
private static byte[] encryptMerchantKey(final byte[] key) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException
{
 KeyFactory keyFact = KeyFactory.getInstance(RSA);
 KeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64.decode("preSharedEncodedKey"));
 PublicKey publicKey = keyFact.generatePublic(spec);
 Cipher cipher = RSA_THREAD_CIPHER.get();
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
 return cipher.doFinal(key);
 }
```

Topic on forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=104446

Comment: Can you link to where it is being referenced?

Comment: Please recheck the question. Added more details. : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=104446

Comment: Can you provide the link to the Amazon Pay Integration Guide that you have mentioned? The link that you have provided to the forum is not related to Amazon Pay, but to AWS Virtual Private Cloud (VPC).

Answer (score 0):

As I figured out that the value will be available at AWS merchant account. I can't post the location of it/screenshot as I don't hold the AWS merchant account. But my client gave the "preSharedEncodedKey" which is a long uuid.